# Create a favorite list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I want to create a favorite list in my application based on user selection. In my app, I use a long JSON file with a bunch of text which is loaded with `$http.get()`.
This is code for displaying content in my view.

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-title></ion-nav-title>
<ion-content>
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="list in items | filter: { id: whichid }">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap"
             ng-repeat="item in list.content | filter: { id2: whichid2 }"
             ng-bind-html="item.description.join('')">
            <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

The basic idea for creating a favorite list is to save displayed text in the array. After that, I can easily print that array in a template for the favorite list.

So the problem is how I can save text/data form expression `({{ item.name }}, {{ item.description }})` to the array? Or if anyone has some other idea for making that favorite list.

Comment: What about a function inside an angular controller that adds a new item to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the item details to a function defined in your controller using ng-click and push it into an array as shown below :

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-title></ion-nav-title>
<ion-content>
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="list in items | filter: { id: whichid }">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="favouriteThis(item)"
             ng-repeat="item in list.content | filter: { id2: whichid2 }"
             ng-bind-html="item.description.join('')">
            <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**In your controller :**
Write the "favouriteThis" function to push the favourited item every time the user clicks on it :

```
$scope.favouriteList = [];
$scope.favouriteThis = function (item) {
 $scope.favouriteList.push(item); // make sure to check for duplicates before pushing the item, the logic for which i've not included here. 
}
```

As you have all the favourited item details in the "$scope.favouriteList", you can use that information in your favourite list directly. To make it more accurate, while checking for duplicates you can also record the number of times user interacted with a particular item using which you can show the most interacted item on the top of the list. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that is a great solution :). But how I can call favouriteThis(item) function outside ng-repeat? For example if I want use this function in header?

Comment: Why do you want to call it from outside the ng-repeat ? You will not be able to record the item details if it's outside. If you put it outside ng-repeat, you don't know when to record the click and which item is clicked.

Comment: Thanks again, I figure it out and now everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a service/controller for this approach since you are making http calls which return JSON objects ***(use a service, as well as a controller)***. In the service have your functions such as getFavorites, addToFavorites, deleteFromFavorites etc. These functions will http GET/POST/UPDATE on your favorites list. Then you will want to return the JSON object to a controller. In the controller you'll have control over the scope and set scope variables to display the data in your app.

Here is a basic example:

**Service**

```
//****************
//Favorite Factory
//****************
.factory('favoriteFactory', function ($http) {
    var favFac = {};
    var favorites = [];

    favFac.getFavorites = function (userId) {
        //$http.get() call to get specific user's favs
    };

    favFac.addToFavorites = function (name, description) {
        //$http.post() call to post to a users favs
    };

    favFac.deleteFromFavorites = function(userId, itemId) {
        //$http.update() call to delete item from users favs   
    }

    return favFac;
});
```

**Controller**

```
     //Favorite Controller
    .controller('FavoritesCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'favoriteFactory', function ($scope, $stateParams, favoriteFactory) {

        //Route current user Id to controller. Pass to service to look up their favorites in db
        var userId = $stateParams.id;

        $scope.favorites = favoriteFactory.getFavorites(userId);
        $scope.addToFavorites = function(name, description){
            favoriteFactory.addToFavorites(name, description);
        }
    }])
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Favorites Page" ng-controller="FavoritesCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-item collection-repeat="favorite in favorites">
        <h3>{{ favorite.name }}</h3>
        <p>{{ favorite.description }}</p>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addToFavorites(favorite.name, favorite.description)">Add</button>
    </ion-item> 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :)